# How to change first array JSON data in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi I am changing json data using onChange event. The first element of array data is not getting changed & other json data are getting changed. How can we change the first data also ?
below is my code -

```
const onChange = (
        selectType: string,
        selectedValue: string,
        selectedId: number
    ): void => {
        
        const arrayData = arrayData1 // where arrayData1 is state
        
        // get question data to to make the changes
        const myQues = arrayData.find(
            (ques) => ques.quesId=== selectedId
        );

        if (myQues) {
            switch (selectType) {
                case Enum.DEMO_VALUE:

                    myQues.answerList.map((answer) => {

                        if(typeof selectedValue === 'string' && 
                        parseInt(selectedValue) <= answer.high  && parseInt(selectedValue) >= answer.low) {
                            answer.value1 = selectedValue;
                            answer.value2 = selectedValue;
                            answer.answered = true
                        } else {
                            answer.value1 = null;
                            answer.value2 = null;
                            answer.answered = false
                        }
                    });
                
                    break;
            }
        }
        setMyArrayData([...arrayData]);
        
    };
```

where

```
answerList = [{
    value1 : null,
    value2 : null,
    answered : false,
    low : 0,
    high : 9
},
{
    value1 : 12,
    value2 : 12,
    answered : true,
    low : 10,
    high : 19
}
{
    value1 : null,
    value2 : null,
    answered : false,
    low : 20,
    high : 300
}]
```

default answer is `12`. When I change value from `12` to `1` then it should go to `answerList[0]` and rest two should be null and `answered` should be false and it is working fine also. But when I change value from `1` to `15` again then it should go to `answerList[1]` and `answerList[0]` & `answerList[2]` should be null and `answered` false but it's not working properly. Both `answerList[0]` & `answerList[1]` are same. Again when I change value from `15` to `151` then `answerList[0]` & `answerList[2]` are same while `answerList[1]` gets fine. In short `answerList[0]` is not getting changed in any condition while `answerList[1]` & `answerList[2]` are getting changed. Why is that ? How can we resolve it ?

Comment: JSON is a string format. If you have JSON, you `JSON.parse` it, otherwise you just have "data" that is JavaScript Objects or arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
answerlist[0]["value"] = 1;
```

try this sir
basically, you want to access the first element in your json array, then in that object you want to change the value property.

more on this here:
[How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)